# DocuSign for Salesforce button logic

Tags: docusign

We are developing a process where we would need the Salesforce button for DocuSign to make a decision for someone.  Trying to determine if a button can be built to look at fields in Salesforce to determine which template to pull from DocuSign, and also to prevent someone from even launching DocuSign if the request hasn’t been approved yet.  Not necessarily looking for code at this point (unless you want to offer that up), but just trying to get an idea if this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at [SalesForce's approval process functionality](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=what_are_approvals.htm). You could use this, and also different page layouts to restrict the Docusign button. This means you could only display the button on approved records, or at different steps during the process display a button to print a 'draft' document.

Comment: Hello!  I know that we can accomplish this through the approval process and record types and page layouts, but from a maintenance standpoint, I'd rather have the button do the work.  I feel like blowing out the approval process based on page layout/record type would make it more complex than it needs to be.